# Are the factors in a time series factor model independent over time?

Tags: time-series, independence, factor-analysis, conditional-independence

Consider the time series extension to the standard factor model:
$$X_t = \Lambda F_t + e_t, \qquad t = 1, 2, \ldots, T$$
where $X_t$ represents \the vector of observations at time $t$, $F_t$ represents the vector of latent factors at time $t$, $\Lambda$ is a factor loading matrix, and $e_t$ is a random vector of idiosyncratic errors. We assume that the factors and errors are uncorrelated and Gaussian, more specifically 
$F_t \sim \mathcal N (0, \operatorname{Id})$ and $e_t \sim \mathcal N (0, \Sigma)$. Also $\Sigma$ is assumed to be diagonal.
I am interested in writing out the so-called *complete likelihood* 
$$p(X_{1:T}, F_{1:T} \:|\: \Lambda, \Sigma)$$
My research seems to suggest that it should be expressed in the following way
\begin{align}
p(X_{1:T}, F_{1:T} \:|\: \Lambda, \Sigma) &= p(X_{1:T} \:|\: F_{1:T}, \Lambda, \Sigma) p(F_{1:T} \:|\: \Lambda, \Sigma ) \\
&= \prod_{t = 1}^T p(X_t \:|\: F_t) p(F_t)
\end{align}
for example see equation 3.19 [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Variational-Approach-to-Factor-Analysis-and-Related-Nielsen/c35a21799c8b253a2dabb0d50e78c8a4e2b2c20c) (Variational Approach to Factor Analysis and Related Models). This particular formulation seems to suggest some things that I have not been able to find sources to back up (hence the reason for this post). It seems to suggest the following:

1. The factors are independent over time, i.e. $F_s \perp F_t$ for all $s \neq t$
2. The observations are conditionally independent over time given the factors, i.e. given $F_t$, $X_t \perp X_s$ for all $s \neq t$

I feel like these are assumptions that *have* to be made because how else would you write the complete likelihood if all you know is the information I stated in the first paragraph of this post? That reasoning is unsatisfactory for me, however. My questions are

- Are the factors assumed to be independent over time?
- Are the observations assumed to be conditionally independent over time?

Any help/clarifications would be appreciated.

Comment: There are multiple, different factor models for time series. It would be helpful to specify which factor model you have in mind.

Comment: Hi: I don't think your first first dot follows from what you wrote previously and what do you mean by the second dot ?

Comment: @RichardHardy - I understand this. I thought that me saying "time series extension to the standard factor model" specified the model I have in mind. I just mean the standard factor model that is also indexed by time. I imagine that what is considered standard may vary which is why I also added the assumptions that I've seen authors make. I will double-check some sources and add them once I find them again.

Comment: @mlofton - the second dot is the no. 2 with no symbols, or at least that's what I hoped it to be.

Comment: @mlofton - I don't believe that no. 1 and no. 2 follow from the assumptions in the first paragraph. I feel like they are needed in order to express the complete likelihood in the way above.

Comment: If you assume that errors and factors are iid then they are independent. Oftentimes you do not, but assume that errors and/or factors are autoregressive processes, in which case you do not have independence. Independence does not follow from some hidden property, it is a direct consequence of your specified model and its assumptions.

Comment: @hejseb - while I certainly appreciate your time in commenting, I don't believe you are understanding my question entirely. I may delete it, work on my phrasing of things and re-post it later. I'm not saying or asking if the independence follows from some hidden property. I am essentially asking if the independence (as stated in no. 1 and no. 2) are implicit assumptions that are made in order to be able to express the complete likelihood as I've expressed it so far.

Comment: You don't need independence in order to be able to evaluate the likelihood analytically. If $F_t$, for example, is an AR(1) process you can do it by means of Kalman filtering. If you *only* receive the information that is given in the first paragraph, you need to make additional assumptions about the dependence structure in order to get anywhere. Again, if $F_t=\phi F_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$, $Var(\epsilon_t)=\sigma^2$ and $\epsilon_t$ is iid and $\sigma^2=(1-\phi^2)$ then marginally $F_t\sim N(0,1)$ but the sequence is *not* independent.

Comment: @hejseb - that is incredibly helpful. When the factors are assumed to be a AR(1) process I believe some authors use the term "dynamic factor model" but I am not concerned about that type of model just yet. Perhaps, I am missing where the authors (for example, in the Variational Approach to Factor Analysis and Related Models paper) are making additional assumptions about the dependence structure among the factors. I will keep reading.

Comment: Exactly, that's what you'd typically call a dynamic factor model. In your specific reference, it is written immediately following (2.36) that the factors and noise are assumed to be uncorrelated and normally distributed (implying independence).

Comment: @hejseb - I understand that jointly normal and uncorrelated implies independent. The sentence makes an assumption about the marginal distributions, at least it does to me. To say $X$ and $Y$ are normal and uncorrelated is not enough to deduce that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: From the context, I think it would be safe to assume joint normality that factorizes into a product of marginals (which are explicitly discussed). It seems to be just a standard factor model for which you do have independence (conditional on the parameters, ie exchangeability). But I guess whether you can assume this is really your question...!

Comment: @SOULed_Outt: I can't help you but check out Eric Zivot's SplusFinmetrics book if you can get your hands on it. He's got a short chapter on factor models that might help with your question.
And my bad for not realizing that the dotted bullet points were just a re-write of the numbered bullet points.

Comment: @mlofton - many thanks for the reference!